# Payment Method displays after Page Refresh

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am using [uc_hotel](https://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel) booking module with Ubercart. When I add a hotel to cart and checkout it shows `No Payment Required` in `Payment Method`.

[image]

After Refreshing the Page it shows the credit card in payment method.

[image]

Why not it displaying the credit card option at first time when I click on `Checkout`.

Comment: Actually it looks like a bug - if order is free it should stay free after refresh, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by unchecking `Free order` from `Payment Method`.